# mutate_at - functions involving two variables

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have a data frame like

```
set.seed(1)    
df <- data.frame(X = 5:14,
       Y = runif(10,0,1),
       Z = runif(10,0,1))
```

I can do

```
df %>% mutate(Y = if_else(X > 10, -Y, Y),
              Z = if_else(X > 10, -Z, Z))
```

But if I have a lot of variables to transform in the same way, I prefer to use mutate_at. However, I don't get it to work properly in this case.

My attempt:

```
testfun <- function(y){if_else(X > 10, -y, y)}
df %>% mutate_at(vars(c("Y","Z")),funs(testfun))
```

But this results in `Evaluation error: object 'X' not found`. I tried variations like `get("X")`, but it didn't work. Does anyone knows a variations that does work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple approach using `mutate_at`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Y,Z), funs(if_else(X > 10, -., .)))

#     X           Y          Z
# 1   5  0.26550866  0.2059746
# 2   6  0.37212390  0.1765568
# 3   7  0.57285336  0.6870228
# 4   8  0.90820779  0.3841037
# 5   9  0.20168193  0.7698414
# 6  10  0.89838968  0.4976992
# 7  11 -0.94467527 -0.7176185
# 8  12 -0.66079779 -0.9919061
# 9  13 -0.62911404 -0.3800352
# 10 14 -0.06178627 -0.7774452
```

Reproducible data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(X = 5:14,
                 Y = runif(10,0,1),
                 Z = runif(10,0,1))
```

Comment: Warning, `funs()` is deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [docendo discimus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50927617/4851597) above, I realise how to use a pre-defined function in this way (docendo's answer works perfectly, I just prefer it like this):

```
testfun <- function(x,y){if_else(x>10, -y, y)}

df%>%mutate_at(vars(Y,Z), funs(testfun(x=X,y=.))
```