# How do I apply a function across multiple pairs of columns in a dataframe?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to apply a function that relies on data from 2 columns across multiple pairs of 2 columns in my dataframe. For example, using tidyverse my df looks like:

```
test_df <- tibble(w = c("yes", "no"), x = c(1, 2), y = c("no", "yes"), z = c(4, 5))
```

I would like to apply the following function:

```
function(a, b) = ifelse(a == "yes", b * 5, b)
```

But I would like to apply this to columns w,x and y,z.

I tried:

```
test_df %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(c(w, y), c(x, z)), function(a,b) ifelse(a == "yes", b * 5, b))
```

But get an error that "b" is undefined. I am hoping not to use a loop for this, as my dataset is very large and I have a lot of column-pairs to iterate through.

I also tried pivot_longer, but there are a lot of other columns in my df as well, so pivot_longer gets messy quickly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50927397/mutate-at-functions-involving-two-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works on your example dataset: it assumes that the columns with numeric values are always preceded by the paired column of yes/no values.

```
library(dplyr)

test_df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), function(x, y = cur_column()) {
    case_when(
      .[, which(colnames(.) == y) - 1] == "yes" ~ x * 5,
      TRUE ~ x
    )
  }))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  w         x y         z
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1 yes       5 no        4
2 no        2 yes      25
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach relies on there being matched pairs of text and numeric columns, and nothing else.

```
library(tidyverse)
char_col <- select(test_df, where(is.character)) %>% colnames
num_col <- select(test_df, where(is.numeric)) %>% colnames
bind_cols(
  select(test_df, all_of(char_col)) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything()),
  select(test_df, all_of(num_col)) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "name2", values_to = "value2")
) %>%
  mutate(value3 = value2 * if_else(value == "yes", 5, 1))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  name  value name2 value2 value3
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 w     yes   x          1      5
2 y     no    z          4      4
3 w     no    x          2      2
4 y     yes   z          5     25
```